# several project in a solution and I can't use properties class inside none of them

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've created a solution with 3 different class project (DLL library) inside it.

Now when I create a Setting and I want to access any of my Settings inside code using `Properties.Settings` I'm not able to do that since compiler shows some error like :

> Only assignment, call, increment,
>   decrement, and new object expressions
>   can be used as a statement

actually the intelisene doesn't give me any hint about properties namespace seems it is missing.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following:

[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Compiler Error CS0201](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k626bk8b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To access your property settings do the following:

```
var mySetting = Properties.Default.aSetting;
```

where aSetting the the name of your setting.

From the error message I'm guessing you are not assigning the setting to anything e.g. just doing

```
 Properties.Default.aSetting;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually libraries (.dll assemblies) are not meant to have their own settings. Rather, all settings should be injected by the host application (.exe) for those libraries. Have a settings class in the host application and inject all the settings to the libraries as needed via their constructor (of course after you retrieve them via `Properties.Settings.Default.xxx` properties of the host application settings).

Comment: you can have setting for a lib though.

Comment: John, that's true but much of a hassle. Justifiable only for utility libraries like loggers, etc.